# android spinner: exception raised during rendering

Tags: android, xml, android-spinner

As soon as I added a `Spinner` in my xml, I got an `Exception raised during rendering: Binary XML file line #-1: Error inflating class <unknown>`.

Clicking on the details, I see the following error.

I fill the `Spinner` programmatically.

[image]

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/title" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/description" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/packaging" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/packaging"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/price" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/available_count" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/availableCount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/category" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/category"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save_product"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="@string/change_product_details" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine may be android studio not able to rebuild the code let's rebuild the code and run again.

Comment: Use latest version 2.2 of Android studio it will solve so many this type of problems. It is also light weight then all it previous verions.

Comment: the latest version I see on their website and the one I have is 2.1

Comment: Below is the url for latest version of android studio read content carefully and download. http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest